# Java OOP triangle existence

Tags: java, oop, input, geometry

I have recently started with programming. So far I have learned basics and now its time for OOP and so i have some questions as im building basic programs to just understand principals and link to way I would use it in practical ways.

So I am making simple triangle program in Java, so far it calculates perimeter (later will ad other shapes and other parameters), I hit the wall where I want to add Triangle existence (as side can't be negative) and also Id like to allow user input. Thing is i don't know where to put code and how to refer to class. Linear (non OOP) way it is simple, but how its done in OOP, do i have to make another class or in Triangle class via methods?

my code:

```
public class Trissturis {
    private int sideA, sideB, sideC;
    private double perimeter;

    public Trissturis(int a, int b, int c) {
        sideA = a;
        sideB = b;
        sideC = c;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return sideA + sideB + sideC;
    }
}

public class TestTri {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Trissturis t1 = new Trissturis(10, 20, 30);
        System.out.println("perimeter is  " + t1.getPerimeter());

        Trissturis t2 = new Trissturis(-1, 20, 30);

    }
}
```

Comment: [Exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: You have declared a field `perimeter` that you don't use anywhere. You could remove that.

Comment: i want to use user input - so user can unput sideA, sideB, sideC, since sides can't be negative or 0 triangle cant exist too. so I want to put in code that checks whether there is negative input. Thing is i don't know where to put that lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate the triangle you have to check that all sides have a length greater than zero, and that no side is longer than the sum of the other two. An method that would accomplish this is:

```
public boolean isValid(){
    return (sideA>0)&&(sideB>0)&&(sideC>0)&&(sideA+sideB>sideC)&&(sideA+sideC>sideB)&&(sideC+sideB>sideA);
}
```

For the user to input values, it is better to have separate user-interface classes. If this will be a desktop application, you could use some of the Swing classes, for example (although there are alternatives).

Comment: perhaps best would be to wrap it in a `boolean` function

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; I've edited the response to include the method "wrapper"

Comment: okay, thanks. this seems to work, but how you then put isValid() method in if else statement in the TestTri class?

Comment: This method could be called, for example, by your user interface classes, once the user has entered all three values for the sides of the triangle. If it returns false then you would show an error message to your user, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface TriangleFactory {

  Triangle create();

}

class ConsoleTriangleFactory implements TriangleFactory {
  @Override
  Triangle create() {
    // read perimeter from console here with some nice prompt
    // check that every side is > 0, 
    // if it's not a number or less than 0 - then do some alert
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to check that the triangle is constructed correctly (with non-negative values, etc) belongs in the Triangle class.

Code to take user input can go in main() in your Test for a small program, but could go in a separate UI namespace for a larger application.

hth